# Cannot properly input text in browser after ubuntu install

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, firefox, brave

ubuntu newbie here. I've installed ubuntu in my laptop (22.04.3 LTS). I already done sudo apt-get update && upgrade and the issue I have is that I cannot properly input text in any browser (both Firefox and Brave). Usually I have to refresh the webpage and even then I cannot properly input my queries (I can maybe enter one or two letters only). Tried with reinstalling the browsers and also I've tried to change the Keyboard Input Method system from ibus to none using the terminal but the issue remains.

Any hints?